# PrimeFaces como colocar background em um DropList

Tags: primefaces

Bom estou usando PrimeFaces em meu projeto e me deparei com a seguinte situação, quando eu tenho um campo alterado que é diferente do original, eu tenho que deixar um background na cor amarela mais especificamente, o porém que está funcionando em outros campos que são inputText mas quando é DropList ou AutoComplete não funciona, alguém tem ideia como fazer?

Código de como estou fazendo abaixo:

```
function verificaValorComValorOriginal () {

    debugger;

    // Dados Básicos
    if ($('#nomePessoa').val() != null && $('#nomePessoaOriginal').val() != null) {
        if ($('#nomePessoa').val() != $('#nomePessoaOriginal').val()) {
            $('#nomePessoa').attr("style","background: yellow;");
            $('#nomePessoaOriginal').attr("style","background: yellow;");
        }
    }

    if ($('#apelido').val() != null && $('#apelidoOriginal').val() != null) {
        if ($('#apelido').val()!= $('#apelidoOriginal').val()) {
            $('#apelido').attr("style","background: yellow;");
            $('#apelidoOriginal').attr("style","background: yellow;");
        }
    }

    if ($('#sexo').val() != null && $('#sexoOriginal').val() != null) {
        if ($('#sexo').val() != $('#sexoOriginal').val()) {
            $('#sexo').attr("style","background: yellow;");
            $('#sexoOriginal').attr("style","background: yellow;");
        }
    }

    if ($('#dataNascimento').val() != null && $('#dataNascimentoOriginal').val() != null) {
        if ($('#dataNascimento').val() != $('#dataNascimentoOriginal').val()) {
            $('#dataNascimento').attr("style","background: yellow;");
            $('#dataNascimentoOriginal').attr("style","background: yellow;");
        }
    }

    if ($('#estadoCivil').val() != null && $('#estadoCivilOriginal').val() != null) {
        if ($('#estadoCivil').val() != $('#estadoCivilOriginal').val()) {
            $('#estadoCivil').attr("style","background: yellow;");
            $('#estadoCivilOriginal').attr("style","background: yellow;");
        }
    }
```

Este é um pequeno exemplo do código, por exemplo esse estadoCivil é um DropList e não funciona quando o valor é diferente. Estou usando PrimeFaces 6.2.

Solução:

```
if ($('#estadoCivil').val() != null && $('#estadoCivilOriginal').val() != null) {
    if ($('#estadoCivil').val() != $('#estadoCivilOriginal').val()) {

        $(".pui-dropdown-label").each(function() {

            if ($(this).context.parentElement.innerHTML.indexOf('estadoCivil') > 0) {
                $(this).attr("style","background: yellow;");
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Por enquanto consegui essa solução acima.

Comment: Por favor poste a resposta como resposta mesmo, mais abaixo. E mais tarde você pode marcar sua própria resposta como aceita. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Solução:

```
if ($('#estadoCivil').val() != null && $('#estadoCivilOriginal').val() != null) {
    if ($('#estadoCivil').val() != $('#estadoCivilOriginal').val()) {

        $(".pui-dropdown-label").each(function() {

            if ($(this).context.parentElement.innerHTML.indexOf('estadoCivil') > 0) {
                $(this).attr("style","background: yellow;");
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Por enquanto consegui essa solução acima.